# Clothing mesh penetrates character when imported into Unreal

Tags: skeletal-animation, maya, skinning, unreal-5

[image: Maya screenshot: no penetration]

I'm trying to import a .fbx file with animation from Maya, but the mesh has changed at some specific frames automatically, which makes my character intersect with the cloth.

The mesh itself does not have any intersection in Maya, so I've narrowed the problem down to import setup in UE5, but I've changed every check box literally, still no luck. The mesh has totally changed at the same frame between Maya and UE5,

[image: UE5 screenshot with penetration at the underarm]

Comment: Note that it's common practice to remove the covered parts of the skin mesh when you add clothes to a character. It removes vertices from the render budget which are not supposed to be visible anyway and it prevents embarrassing wardrobe malfunctions like this.